# Show a hidden latte-dock by hovering cursor over it

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma, latte-dock

I have recently switched from GNOME to KDE.  I had previously used the DashtoDock GNOME extension, and am now using Latte to achieve the same on KDE.  As far as I've read, it's the recommended dock to use with Plasma.

One thing I'm hitting a snag with is "showing" a hidden dock. For example when I have behaviour set to auto-hide, I cannot find any way to reveal the dock.  For Dodge-Maximised etc the only solution I have found is to set a keyboard shortcut.  I can live with that if I have to, but is there no way to make it show when moving the cursor to the edge of the screen?

I am using Kubuntu 20.04 LTS, and have Plasma 5.18.5.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you placed the dock in the left or right side of the screen? If so , yes there's a problem with the dock that never shows up when it goes hidden.Looks like a bug. And AFAIK there's no way to **reveal** it via **screen edges**  in KDE Plasma. Screen edges feature is only for some of the **KWin** plugins.

Comment: But there's an alternative.You can use [Cairo-dock](https://glx-dock.org/). Although it's better integrated with Gnome desktop and Gtk but you can also use it in KDE Plasma. And there's no such problem with it when you place it in the left or right side of the screen.You can install it via ```sudo apt install cairo-dock```. Although Docky works well too , but you cannot place it anywhere other than the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and finally found the answer.

Wrong way : I was adding latte dock as a widget by right clicking on the desktop and clicking on "Add widgets".

Good way : The proper way to do this is to start latte dock as an application, from the terminal :

> latte-dock

Then in the system settings, make sure to add latte-dock in the autostart applications.

Comment: So I believe I originally launched it from the activities menu.  Not sure which of the above this is similar to.

In the end I jumped ship from KDE to XFCE.  I don't think I scratched the surface with the customisability available in KDE.  It was quite resource heavy, and I was also constantly getting "A service has crashed" messages, and my clipboard would randomly fail -- nightmare as someone who spends a lot of time coding!  With XFCE I've ended up with something much lighter, and still as customisable as I need to get an identical aesthetic :) **With a dock that appears when I hover!

Comment: Ok, what is your system hardware ? I've tried Xfce but it looked so old to me. I didn't try to configure it though. Kubuntu 20.04 works well for my 8G Ram, Intel CORE i5, 1.8GHz HP laptop. I've also tried KDE Neon but some Qt libraries where not compatible (may be too recent ?) with the software I wanted to install (QGIS 3.16). Anyway, glad to see that you found a suitable solution :)

Comment: It's gettin on a wee bit, but I have an overclocked (3rd gen) i5, 16Gb RAM, gtx970.  Don't get me wrong it wasn't exactly dragging its knuckles, but I did note the larger base-load than say gnome with a bunch of extensions running.  Neon is cool, but of course bleeding edge which could also be why you ran into a couple of issues.  Good for play, but maybe not for my work machine!  Vanilla XFCE is pretty old school, but a [little bit of tweaking](https://ibb.co/4830pYm) and I achieved an almost identical look and feel to my KDE set up.